# Write a function to reverse (??) a number

Tags: functions

I am not sure if `reverse` is a good name for that function but anyway, I'll describe its inputs and desired outputs.

```
1 -> 5
2 -> 4
3 -> 3
4 -> 2
5 -> 1
```

That's the domain and range for that function:

$$
f:\{1,2,3,4,5\}  \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}
$$

I'm sorry if all of this is very obvious but I really cannot find a simple description for that function. I'd be happy to at least hear its proper name.

Comment: How about _domain reversal_?

Comment: Say to "complement" the number.

Comment: $f(x)=6-x$ ? How about [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection)?

Comment: @lhf Yes, that was it! Thank you!

Comment: seems like a computer science question to me or a programming one not a math one as you have Vecrev in PARI/GP for example, and I've written a few reverse scripts myself. maybe f(x)=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_(mathematics)  where the indexes are in reverse order.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes, the context was indeed a programming one. And I literally was looking for a way to reverse indexes in an existing loop. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu maybe the programming stack exchange would be a better place then , all you need to reverse the index in a for loop is a forstep loop that has a negative step.

Comment: Geometrically it's a _reflection_, but it's also a _complement, relative_ to the number $6.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an *expression*, try
$$
f(x) = 6 -x
$$

If you want a name, try *reflection* through the center or *central reflection*. 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection) also suggests *central inversion*.

Comment: I was looking both for the simplest _expression_ to achieve that and a name for it. You came up with both of them. Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: @lhf: *complement* is more common in arithmetic and programming terminology (example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Decimal_example). Reflection is more often done around the origin 0.

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer was from @lhf. The answer is:

$$
f(x)=6-x
$$

As I thought, it was very simple and I was just missing the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

"The reverse operation" is a perfectly good description of this function, especially if you give an explicit example (such as the one in your post) when you first introduce the term.

Comment: Reversal is used in the context of bit reversal, i.e. mirroring left-to-right. I would never understand "reverse" with the meaning of complement.

Comment: @Yves: "Reversal" is used in the context of reversal. This example *is* mirrored. I'm sure you would understand "reverse" when the term is paired with an example. What does complements have to do with anything?

Comment: it seems that you never heard of 2's complement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Or, I simply have no idea what you think complements (whether referring to 2's complement or any other phrase) have to do with the question at hand. (or what you think it has to do with bit reversal)

Comment: @Hurkyl : You posted a polite, on-topic, and honest comment in a thread in which two other users were off-topic, abusive, and dishonest, and I see that the moderators have responded to my report by deleting all of the comments including yours, even though you were not one of the offenders. Posting here is an irregular and inconvenient mode of responding to your comment, but I don't know if any other is available now. You said you would vote to close the question about the limp piece of string. Your exact words are no longer available to me, but I posted an$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$answer, now of course deleted, saying that I suspected when I posted the question, that some would vote to close the limp-string problem on the grounds you mentioned. One thing I wanted to find out was whether some would say pretty much exactly what you said. For the record, I disagree about that. On another matter related to that question: In 1998 I showed it to Gian-Carlo Rota, professor of applied mathematics and philosophy at MIT, and he said it was a very good problem and he might assign it the next time he taught geometric probability. But he died the following April. @Hurkyl

Comment: @Hurkyl : The item to which I refer is this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26642/criteria-for-closing-of-questions